# DataFrame.apply() error: "<Series> is not a valid function for 'Series' object"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I get an AttributeError from pandas.DataFrame.apply(). Despite that, the function appears to work, but I'd like to understand apply() better, so I'm posting this question anyway...

I have two dataframes, like these:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'ID': ['123', '456', '789'],
    'TIME': [1.5, 2, 3]
})

b = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'ID': ['123', '456', '789'] * 2,
    'TIME_START': [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 5],
    'TIME_END': [5, 4, 6, 6, 3, 6],
    'CORR_KEY': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr']
})
```

I merge them like so:

```
c = a.merge(b, how = 'inner', on = 'ID')
```

And I get the following:

```
print(c)

    ID  TIME  TIME_START  TIME_END CORR_KEY
0  123   1.5           1         5      abc
1  123   1.5           2         6      jkl
2  456   2.0           3         4      def
3  456   2.0           1         3      mno
4  789   3.0           3         6      ghi
5  789   3.0           5         6      pqr
```

Now I need to drop records in **c** where **TIME_START** <= **TIME** <= **TIME_END** is FALSE. This way, I wind up with only records that have the relevant **CORR_KEY**. (For example, the correct **CORR_KEY** for **ID** 123 is abc, NOT jkl.)

I use the following function, and apply it along the dataframe:

```
def drop_records(df):
    start_condition = df['TIME_START'] <= df['TIME']
    end_condition = df['TIME'] <= df['TIME_END']

    df.drop(df[~(start_condition) | ~(end_condition)].index, inplace = True)

    return df

c = c.apply(drop_records(c))
```

The result is:

> AttributeError: 'ID' is not a valid function for 'Series' object

HOWEVER, checking **c** again, I get the expected output:

```
print(c)

    ID  TIME  TIME_START  TIME_END CORR_KEY
0  123   1.5           1         5      abc
3  456   2.0           1         3      mno
4  789   3.0           3         6      ghi
```

So, what causes the AttributeError?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the `apply` the dataframe is divided in series, one for each column, and the function is applied to serie. Since `ID` is just first column, `apply` is trying to execute `drop_records(c)` but sending them the serie of `ID` which will result in an `AttributeError`.

You don't neet to `apply` a function here, just:

```
c = drop_records(c)
```

Or using boolean masks:

```
mask = (c.TIME_START <= c.TIME) & (c.TIME <= c.TIME_END)
c = c[mask]
```

Or even query as @Sandeep Kadapa suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestions, I definitely need to refactor my code. Still slightly confused on apply() though - why does **c** get altered as expected if what I am really doing is feeding in one series at a time?

Comment: Because the `drop_records(c)` is actually returning information, so it assigned to `c` what fails is `c` trying to send `ID` series as a parameter of the function. Indeed you are trying to feed one series to a function that is not expecting any parameter.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. The `inplace` argument in `drop_records` makes the changes to **c**, and then **c** gets passed into the `apply` method which throws the `AttributeError`. That makes sense. It also occurs to me that the `inplace` argument would be redundant here. I only set it out of habit.

Comment: I accepted this answer since these comments address my actual question. I did wind up using the `query` method in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You are overkilling the solution. You can use `query` to directly get your output:

```
c = c.query('TIME_START <= TIME <= TIME_END')

print(c)
    ID  TIME  TIME_START  TIME_END CORR_KEY
0  123   1.5           1         5      abc
3  456   2.0           1         3      mno
4  789   3.0           3         6      ghi
```

Comment: Wow, I did not realize this method existed. This would have saved me so much time in other contexts as well! Thank you.